# Getting this trigger to work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

My DB has more tables but those two are the only ones used in the trigger.

Any Ideas why is not working?

See link below.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa270/1

Comment: You're using a trigger syntax that's not valid for T-SQL/SQL Server. E.g. SQL Server doesn't have a `FOR EACH ROW` option, nor does SQL Server know `Salario]%type;` - seems to be an Oracle or MySQL trigger. You need to learn what the T-SQL/SQL Server equivalents are (if any) and rewrite the trigger

Comment: In addition, no one reading your question has any idea of what "not working" means. Help yourself by helping others understand your situation. Describe precisely what does occur (including the complete text of any error messages) and what you expect to occur. And providing a complete script that demonstrates your situation (not just DDL) will encourage others.